# Conectar sitio de localhost a base de datos online ¿Es posible?

Tags: php, mysql

La pregunta es si puedo conectar una web guardada en mi localhost a una base de datos que se encuentre alojada online, la idea es la siguiente:

> *Tengo una base de datos en linea con la informacion necesaria para que
>   corra mi website, tambien tengo registrado el domino theeye.ml que
>   basicamente crea un iframe de tu localhost, tengo usbwebserver (Un
>   localhost portable) en varios pendrives, la idea es que uno inicie
>   localhost con el pendrive y entre a **www.theeye.ml** y pueda correr el
>   blog que se actualiza con la base de datos online*

Osea que para iniciar el sitio **theeye.ml** sea necesario el pendrive con el localhost, pero que la base de datos no este guardada en el localhost sino en un hosting en linea Soy novato con mysql, disculpen la ignorancia y gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normalmente en tu cPanel tienes las direcciones a las que se puede conectar con Mysql 
si usas PHP 5+ te recomiendo usar mysqli:

```
$conexion = mysqli_connect("host","usuario","password","db");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_connect('elDominioDeLaBase.com','usuario','contraseña');
```

Si es posible, la única restricción que puede suceder es que haya algún firewall que no permita la conexión al host remoto y que tu servidor SQL tenga [registradas las IP's autorizadas](https://geekytheory.com/como-permitir-el-acceso-remoto-a-una-base-de-datos-mysql) para conectar (puedes permitir la conexión a cualquier ip).

Comment: Si se puede conectar como de costumbre? Muchas gracias

Comment: Si, como de costumbre, en tu servidor mysql debes habilitar las ips a las que quieres permitir el acceso, o abrirla a cualquier ip.